# How to import an ES6 package into an Express Typescript Project that is shared by a Vite React package?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, shared-libraries

I am trying to share common zod models and JS functions between the backend (Express & TS) and frontend (Vite React) with a shared library housed on a gcloud npm repo. The shared library **works perfectly on the frontend**, however I am constantly receiving errors such as the following on the backend.

Note that the ResponseErrorModel seems to work fine on the backend, however the PatientModel and LoginFormModel do not work, no matter what I tried (all relevant solutions found in 10 hours of troubleshooting and research).

- If I add type module or jscommon to the Backend package.json config, the error is gone but the full stack application no longer works: `LoginRequest.ts:4          POST http://localhost:8080/api/login 500 (Internal Server Error)`
- I've tried all known permutations of the Backend package.json and ts.configs related to ES/Common, entry point, index.ts vs. index.json.
- I've tried importing the LogingFormModel directly with the 'export * from ./forms/LoginModel', I've also tried removing the * and replacing with {LoginModel}

**Error: "Unexpected Token 'export'"**

[image]

**The Library Information:**

*package.json*

```
{
  "name": "@something/something-shared",
  "version": "1.0.13",
  "description": "A nice greeter",
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "types": "lib/index.d.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rimraf lib/*",
    "build": "tsc",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "lint": "tslint -p tsconfig.json",
    "prepare": "npm run build",
    "prepublishOnly": "npm run lint",
    "preversion": "npm run lint",
    "postversion": "git push && git push --tags",
    "patch": "npm version patch",
    "publish": "npm publish",
    "artifact-registry-login": "npx google-artifactregistry-auth"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "someone",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^18.15.11",
    "prettier": "^2.8.7",
    "rimraf": "^4.4.1",
    "tslint": "^6.1.3",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.18.0",
    "typescript": "^5.0.2"
  },
  "files": [
    "lib/**/*"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "zod": "^3.21.4"
  }
}
```

*tsconfig.json*

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./lib",
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "Node"
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/__tests__/*"]
}
```

**The Backend Information**

*Structure of Lib when Imported*

[image]

backend package.json

```
{
  "name": "something-backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "concurrently \"npx tsc --watch\" \"nodemon -q dist/index.js\"",
    "build": "npx tsc",
    "start": "node dist/index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@something/something-shared": "^1.0.13",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "kysely": "^0.23.5",
    "pg": "^8.10.0",
    "zod": "^3.21.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/node": "^18.15.11",
    "@types/pg": "^8.6.6",
    "concurrently": "^8.0.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.22",
    "prettier": "^2.8.7",
    "typescript": "^5.0.2"
  }
}
```

*backend tsconfig.json* : I've tried different targets and module types.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "target": "es2016",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else stumbles on this issue, the root cause seems to be that certain common tooling isn't playing nicely across the library and backend, probably because of different syntax and tooling interplay. The module/target settings from the ts config in BOTH the backend express app and the shared library matching (and rebuilding/redeployment the shared library) is what solved it Most likely... it's a careful interplay I think between the older tech of express and something reasonably modern for the front end (Is my best understand of what I did).

**Shared Library**

*package.json*

Target and Module for this library were set to ESNext (Which express environment can't handle), now they match.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./lib",
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "Node"
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/__tests__/*"]
}
```

*ts.config*

No change and no `"type": "module or commonjs"`

**Backend Express**

*package.json*

Set the following, ensuring the root index file is ts not js

```
  "main": "index.ts",
  "type": "commonjs",
```

*ts.config*

Works, same target and module as the shared library and the frontend can also still understand the shared lib without modification (thus overcoming a limitation of express I believe.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "strict": true
  }
}
```